# undefined reference when using makefile

Tags: c, makefile, header-files

I have a given makefile, written by our Professor.

```
SHELL  = /bin/bash
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -W -std=c99 -pedantic
LIBS   =

# Rajouter le nom des executables apres '=', separes par un espace.
# Si une ligne est pleine, rajouter '\' en fin de ligne et passer a la suivante.

# To compile without bor-util.c file 
EXECS = main

# To compile with bor-util.c file 
EXECSUTIL = 

# To compile with bor-util.c & bor-timer.c files
EXECSTIMER = 


.c.o :
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c

help ::
    @echo "Options du make : help all clean distclean"

all :: $(EXECS) $(EXECSUTIL) $(EXECSTIMER)

$(EXECS) : %: %.o 
    $(CC) -o $@ $@.o $(LIBS)

$(EXECSUTIL) : %: %.o bor-util.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $@.o bor-util.o $(LIBS)

$(EXECSTIMER) : %: %.o bor-util.o bor-timer.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $@.o bor-util.o bor-timer.o $(LIBS)

clean ::
    \rm -f *.o core

distclean :: clean
    \rm -f *% $(EXECS) $(EXECSUTIL) $(EXECSTIMER)
```

All we have to do in this project, is to write our code in other file and use this makefile to compile as usual.
I've written a helloWorld function to test. I have 3 files

FUNCTIONS.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "functions.h"

void printMsg(){
    printf("Hello World !");
}
```

FUNCTIONS.H

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

void printMsg();
#endif /* FUNCTIONS_H */
```

And a MAIN.C file to test out everything

```
#include "functions.h"


int main(){
    
    printMsg(); 
    return 0;
}
```

and I've added `main` to the makefile. But I get this error message when I compile

```
gcc -o main main.o 
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `printMsg'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:32: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Does anyone know what's the solutions please ? Thank you

Comment: Did you add function.c in the makefile?

Comment: By the way, the makefile done by your teacher is  ugly. Allez l'OM au passage

Comment: Do you wish to rename your files to obey the makefile, or rewrite the makefile to accept your files?

Comment: @NicolasGuerin yes I've already add functions.c but it didn't work

Comment: @NicolasGuerin Oh no, I think the code is slightly elegant :) Viva Marsilia :D

Comment: @Beta I was trying to edit my makefile to accept and compile the whole project. it seems that the makefile needed some changes of its code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is clear: the linker did not find the `printMsg` function. And this is perfectly normal: the link command that was executed was:

```
gcc -o main main.o
```

See? No trace of `functions.o` where the `printMsg` function is implemented. To fix this you must link with this command:

```
gcc -o main main.o functions.o
```

The problem is that your Makefile does not mention `functions.o` as a pre-requisite of `main` and it does not use it neither in the recipe. Either you did not understand the professor's instructions (who did not ask you to add `functions.c` and `functions.h`), or you forgot that he also indicated how to update the Makefile, or his Makefile is not compatible with his own instructions. In the two last cases you can adapt the Makefile by changing the rule for `$(EXECS)`:

```
$(EXECS) : %: %.o functions.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

`$^` expands as the list of all pre-requisites, that is, in your case, `main.o functions.o`. This new rule will:

1. Re-build `main` if `main.o` or `functions.o` changed.
2. Link `main.o` **and** `functions.o`.

Warning: if you have other executables listed in `$(EXECS)` that do not depend on `functions.o`, or that depend on other object files, or if you have more other files like `functions.o`, you will need something a bit more sophisticated. Ask a new question.

Note: as SO is English, it is better to translate the French comments in your example code. I suggest:

> Add the executable names after '=', separated by one space.
>   If a line is full, add a '\' at the end and continue on the next line.

One last note: letter case matters. If your file is `functions.c` do not type `FUNCTIONS.C` in your question. Same with the other file names.

Comment: + I will take your remarks about the "question syntax" in consideration for future questions since I'm a new member here. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Use this makefile it works and it is more comprehensible/better

```
GREEN   = \033[1;32m

WHITE   = \033[0;m

NAME    = main

CC      = gcc -g

RM      = rm -f

SRCS    = functions.c    \
          main.c

OBJS    = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CFLAGS = -I ./include/
CFLAGS += -W -Wall -Wextra

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
         @$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(NAME) $(LDFLAGS)
         @printf "\n[$(GREEN)OK$(WHITE)] Binary : $(NAME)\n"
         @echo "-------------------\n"

%.o :    %.c
         @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
         @printf "[$(GREEN)OK$(WHITE)] $<\n"

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re
```

The functions.h file :

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_
#define FUNCTIONS_H_

void printMsg();

#endif /* !FUNCTIONS_H_ */
```

And the same main.c. You don't need to include "functions.h" in the function.c

Allez l'om,

Nicolas :)